# How to store a file in C

Tags: c

I am creating a program and this example is the best way I can represent it.
Lets say I have a Hello_World program that is already compiled (Using c).
What I want to know is how can I make a C script that will create a file that is a copy of the .exe from Hello_World (script run at complied time). 
However I would be running the program on another computer where Hello_World doesn't exist.
How would I go about creating it ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you do a quick google search, you will find a plethora of tutorials.

Comment: Everything that I have found is either reading an already existing file or copying a file but never have it stored in the executable.

Comment: There is no real difference between a `.txt` and `.exe`. They are just a bunch of 1s and 0s, so you can copy an executable just as you would copy a text file.

Comment: I'm sorry the only way I know to copy a text file is by using fopen() which won't work and copying and pasting the code. I am really lost and could use some help.

Comment: Then `fopen()` the executable and do the same. There is absolutely no difference on how you do the copy. The format of the file is irrelevant.

Comment: If I fopen() then the file will be read. I want it to be stored so that the file doesn't have to be there when executed.

Comment: That is possible depending on the OS. Modern OSes have memory protection which don't allow these kind of operations. But if you go ahead and disable all of those security features, you can send and load the binary remotely into memory and execute it. And that still involves pretty advanced stuff.

Comment: *However I would be running the program on another computer where Hello_World doesn't exist* Just send the file (executable) to the remote machine and execute. What is the issue here?

Comment: Some reading: https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Harbour/Whitepaper/bh-usa-07-harbour-WP.pdf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639006/is-it-possible-to-load-a-binary-file-into-memory-and-execute-it-in-windows https://superuser.com/questions/241259/how-to-run-a-local-application-on-a-distant-server-with-ssh

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya That is exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: @drum Thank you for your answer and I have a lot of looking into this to do. Please make your comments an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You don't normally include the file _in_ the exe (although that's possible). You would just include it next to the exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible depending on the OS. Modern OSes have memory protection which don't allow these kind of operations. But if you go ahead and disable all of those security features, you can send and load the binary remotely into memory and execute it. And that still involves pretty advanced stuff.

Some reading:

- https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Harbour/Whitepaper/bh-usa-07-harbour-WP.pdf
- https://superuser.com/questions/241259/how-to-run-a-local-application-on-a-distant-server-with-ssh
- [Is it possible to load a binary file into memory and execute it in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639006/is-it-possible-to-load-a-binary-file-into-memory-and-execute-it-in-windows)